# How can I have a discord bot interpret a string/word that I enter as an argument in a command as something different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Currently, I have some code that allows me to run a command like this:

```
!modify [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1.5, 1] [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2.05, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2]
```

which will have the bot output this

> "[6.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.0, 12.0, 4.0]"

or a command like this:

```
 !modify [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2.05, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2]
```

which will have the bot output this

> "[6.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.1, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 8.0, 4.0]"

Here is the code for interpretation purposes:

```
@client.command()
async def modify(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.channel.id != 850806578125864981:
        return
    else:
        sets = [] # stocking every sets found
        subset = [] #I call a 'set' a pair of brackets

        for arg in args:
            subset.append(float(''.join([car for car in arg if car.isnumeric() or car == '.']))) # just extracting the numerical part of the element
            if ']' in arg: #closing a set
                sets.append(subset)
                subset = [] # creating a new one

        output = [*sets[0]] # number of the first set

        for s in sets[1:]: # looping over every other sets
            for i in range(len(s)):
                output[i] *= s[i] # multiplying the numbers together

        embed=discord.Embed(title="g.stats helper", url="private!", description=f":white_check_mark: - Here is your new custom g.stat: \n\n **{output}**", color=0x77AC54)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But the thing I'm having a problem with is adding a word like "g.basic" that can be used as an argument in the command which I would want the bot to interpret as `"[18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]"` so basically sending `!modify [18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]` would be identical to sending `!modify g.basic`

The command takes the number of strings provided (the []s) and multiplies all the numbers inside of them to output a final answer. I would like to know how to specify certain words that can be used that the bot would interpret as one of these long 13-number-long number strings. This sounds complicated but I'm in desperate need of some help.

Comment: What I understood is basically you want to call this bot function without having to write `!modify`?

Comment: @Goion No, I want to be able to write !modify g.basic and the bot would interpret that as the same thing as writing !modify [18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]

Comment: But where is g.basic defined? Like in discord you are going to do `!g.basic = [18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]`. Or any time you write a list, it would save it as `g.basic` in the bot.

Comment: See, this is the thing, I don't know how to incorporate it into the code. I want to store g.basic in the function so anything you put it as an argument the bot will interpret it as [18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]

Basically it isn't defined yet. So the bot doesn't know to look for it

Comment: Why not hard code it as a variable? And if someone messages `!modify g.basic` You don't perform any operations on args. Instead you return that variable.

Comment: It's fine, found my answer inside of the Python discord